# React Removes Inline Styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inline-styles

I'm writing an HTML email using React. Like any good HTML email, I'm using inline styles that target legacy clients such as Microsoft Outlook. Some styles are being removed by React during rendering. How do I add support for these styles or work around this issue? Styles must be inlined.

Here's an example:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const style = {
    fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
    msoHide: 'all'
  }

  return(
    <div style={style}>
      Some text goes here...
    </div>
  )
}
```

When rendered, the `mso-hide: all` style is removed:

```
<div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
  Some text goes here...
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you apply it via class?

Comment: @Dadsquatch Styles need to be inlined. A class would be fine otherwise.

Comment: Could it be possible that its not React, but the browser that strips this out?

Comment: @putvande Good question. This could be the case when using JavaScript to set an unsupported style. I’m honestly not sure. But, I still need a workaround to get all necessary styles inlined using React. In the same way that I could simply write `<div style="unsupported-property-name: all;">` using pure HTML, and the browser wouldn't strip it from the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

The docs say that vendor-specific properties in a style object must start with a capital letter, e.g. `WebkitAppearance` rather than `webkitAppearance`. They also say that `ms` is an exception to that rule. [See here](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html).

Still, this is `mso`. Does `MsoHide` work?

Comment: I'd seen this and tried a few variations like `MsoHide`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work.